# Entity Framework lazy loading don't work, keep bringing child array

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, code-first

This is my first Code-first project and I have a problem with entity lazy loading.

Let me show my classes.
Very simple parent like entities:

```
public class Empresas
{
    …

    //Cidade
    public int? IdCidade { get; set; }
    public Cidades Cidade { get; set; }
}
```

And this:

```
public class Cidades
{
    …

    public virtual ICollection<Empresas> Empresas { get; set; }
}
```

Relation Map:

```
public EmpresasMap()
{
    ToTable("Empresas");

    …

    HasOptional<Cidades>(t => t.Cidade).WithMany(t => t.Empresas).HasForeignKey(c => c.IdCidade);
}
```

The DbContext (Lazy Loading disabled):

```
public partial class MedienDataContext : DbContext
{
    public MedienDataContext() : base("CnnStr")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MedienDataContext>(null);
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is, when I execute a function to return "Empresas", including "Cidades", the returned Json brings the "Cidade.Empresas" element filled in to all records, how do I prevent this from happening?

Method:

```
public List<Empresas> GetEmpresasByTipo(string tipo) 
{
     return _context.Empresas
                    .Include("Cidade")
                    .Where(x => x.Tipo == tipo).ToList();
}
```

Web Api Controller Method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getbytipo/{tipo}")]
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetByTipo(string tipo)
{
    try
    {
       List<Empresas> empresas = _repository.GetEmpresasByTipo(tipo);
       return CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, empresas);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
   {
       return CreateErrorResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Erro ao retornar.", e.Message);
   }

}
```

Example JSON Returned at Postman after serialization:

```
[
   {
      "idEmpresa":2,
      "tipo":"G",
      "IdCidade":1,
      "Cidade":{
         "idCidade":1,
         "cidade":"Ribeirão Preto",
         "empresas":[       //Here the problematic array
            {
               "idEmpresa":3,
               "tipo":"G",
               "IdCidade":1
            },
            {
               "idEmpresa":4,
               "tipo":"G",
               "IdCidade":1
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "idEmpresa":3,
      "tipo":"G",
      "IdCidade":1,
      "Cidade":{
         "idCidade":1,
         "cidade":"Ribeirão Preto",
         "empresas":[ //Here the problematic array
            {
               "idEmpresa":2,
               "tipo":"G",
               "IdCidade":1
            },
            {
               "idEmpresa":4,
               "tipo":"G",
               "IdCidade":1
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "idEmpresa":4,
      "tipo":"G",
      "IdCidade":1,
      "Cidade":{
         "idCidade":1,
         "cidade":"Ribeirão Preto",
         "empresas":[ //Here the problematic array
            {
               "idEmpresa":2,
               "tipo":"G",
               "IdCidade":1
            },
            {
               "idEmpresa":3,
               "tipo":"G",
               "IdCidade":1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: This `.Where(x => x.Tipo == tipo)` is causing it to load the `empresas`. Execute that against the `Empresas` instead.

Comment: Hi Yoshi, thanks for answer, I tried to remove the where condition but the same problem happened.